# How to get cookie information in blackberry HttpConnection

Tags: blackberry, cookies

I'm sending request to the server and I'm getting the html response. But 
I want to store the cookie information. Is there any other classes or methods 
available to get the cookie information in blackberry.

```
for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
  String key = httpConn.getHeaderFieldKey(j);
  String field = httpConn.getHeaderField(j);
  if (key == null && j > 0) {
    break;
  }
  add(new RichTextField(key + " : " + field));
}
```

I used this code to get the header information, but I didnt get-setcookie header ( which I'm supposed to get). the output is as follows.

```
Connection: Close
expires: -1
date: Tue, 08 Mar 2011..........
server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
x-powered-by: ASP.NET
pragma:no-cache
x-rim-etag:4626353C5B58791ACD00D30EAADEAF4663FE219F
cache-control: no-cache, no-store
x-aspnet-version:2.0.50727
content-location:http://beemediahive...........
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

How do I get cookie information in blackberry?

Answer (score 0):

check out below link:
http://esgroupmobile.wordpress.com/2009/05/29/blackberry-development-tip-http-get/

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.